# Регулярное выражение. Поиск повторяющихся цифр

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть вот такая строка:

```
---011110000-----
```

Нужно найти 3 повторяющиеся цифры если нет 4-ёх повторяющихся цифр.

Например:

- `---011110000-----` не должно быть совпадений
- `---01110000------` должно совпасть только с 111
- `-----0111000-----` должно совпасть и с 000 и с 111

Помогите составить регулярку для JavaScript.

**P.S. `((?=(\d{1}))\2{3})` это выражение даст совпадение в каждом примере...**

Comment: Ваш вопрос неправильно (неполно/некорректно/нелогично) сформулирован. `Нужно найти 3 повторяющиеся цифры если нет 4-ёх повторяющихся цифр.` Данное условие противоречит `---01110000------ должно совпасть только с 1`

Comment: Спасибо, поправил. Конечно я имел ввиду 111 и 000

Comment: Решает ли выражение https://regex101.com/r/yT5sD9/1 желаемые задачи? Результат во второй группе.

Comment: Спасибо! Это то что нужно!

Comment: Какой результат должен быть на тексте `----1111111-----` ?

Comment: Такая строка отфильтруется раньше и не будет проходить эту проверку.

Comment: @ReinRaus, оформите свое решение как ответ.

Comment: @Visman он мне не нравится. Чуть позже сделаю общее нормальное решение данной задачи применительно к JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А как на счёт двух регулярок?

```
'---011110000-----'.replace(/(\d)\1{3}/g,'-').match(/(\d)\1{2}/g)
→ null

'---011110000-----'.replace(/(\d)\1{3}/g,'-').match(/(\d)\1{2}/g)
→ ["111"]

'-----0111000-----'.replace(/(\d)\1{3}/g,'-').match(/(\d)\1{2}/g)
→ ["111", "000"]
```

С одной регуляркой удалось только захватить символ, после которого идёт тройка:

```
 '---011110000-----'.match(/(.)(?=(\d)\2{2}(?!\2))(?!\1)/g)
 → null

 '---01110000------'.match(/(.)(?=(\d)\2{2}(?!\2))(?!\1)/g)
 → ["0"]

 '-----0111000-----'.match(/(.)(?=(\d)\2{2}(?!\2))(?!\1)/g)
 → ["0", "1"]
```

Comment: Спасибо! Это работает. Но, все же, хотелось бы решить эту задачу с помощью одной регулярки. Пока буду использовать Ваше решение.

Answer (score 3):

Частный случай, который подходит под нужды ТС довольно прост:

```
(?=.(\d))(?!\1)(?=.(\1{3})(?!\1))
```

https://regex101.com/r/yT5sD9/1

---

Гораздо интереснее сформулировать задачу так:

> Найти непрерывную последовательность, состоящую из литерала, повторенного **N** раз.

Здесь уже решение будет весьма нетривиальным за счет слишком малого функционала регулярных выражений в JavaScript.
Решение выглядит так:

```
(?:(?=((?=([^]))(?=\2{0,2}(?!\2)|\2{4,}(?!\2))\2+(?!\2)))\1)*(([^])\4{2}(?!\4))
```

Кратко его можно описать так:
Сымитировав атомарную группировку захватываем все непрерывные последовательности длиной, отличной от **N**, а после этого захватываем непрерывную последовательность длиной **N**. Результат в четвертой группе (результатом считается любой символ повторенный подряд ровно 3 раза, не только цифры)

Посмотреть можно здесь:
https://regex101.com/r/yT5sD9/2

Общий вид в зависимости от **N**:

```
(?:(?=((?=([^]))(?=\2{0,[N-1]}(?!\2)|\2{[N+1],}(?!\2))\2+(?!\2)))\1)*(([^])\4{[N-1]}(?!\4))
```

Comment: Выражение `(?=.(\d))(?!\1)(?=.(\1{3})(?!\1))` успешно находит необходимое количество повторений, но для получения подстроки его не достаточно. Будет идеально, если `'---0111000-----'.match(/(?=.(\d))(?!\1)(?=.(\1{3})(?!\1))/g)` вернет искомую подстроку.

Comment: Для этого есть exec, а не match.

Comment: match отличается от exec только тем, что если есть флаг g, то начинает поиск с позиции lastIndex?,не суть.
->`/(?=.(\d))(?!\1)(?=.(\1{3})(?!\1))/g.exec('---0111000-----')

<-["", "1", "111"]`

Comment: Чему равна «искомая подстрока» в этом примере?

Comment: `---0111000-----` соответственно должно совпасть и 111 и 000

Comment: Вечером посмотрю в чем проблема. На этом тексте в тесте 2 совпадения, а не одно.  https://regex101.com/r/yT5sD9/1

Comment: @molinero match всегда возвращает группу `$0` что невозможно в данном регулярном выражении- его важным условием является нулевая длина совпадения. Используйте `exec` в цикле. `Если указан флаг "g", то повторный вызов exec будет давать следующее совпадение` http://javascript.ru/RegExp/exec

Comment: Понятно. В таком случае удобней использовать две регулярки из первого ответа. Спасибо всем за участие. Не могли бы вы посоветовать хороший материал для изучения capturing group регулярных выражений?

Comment: Такого материала не существует... Сохраняющая группа - это просто сохранение совпавшего текста в отдельную переменную... Это все равно как искать материал по присвоению значения переменной... Прочтите Фридла, если интересны регексы. В вики есть ссылка [tag:регулярные-выражения]

Comment: Про регулярки (в т. ч. про захватываемые и незахватываемые группы) довольно разумно написано у Крокфорда в книге JavaScript: Сильные стороны

Comment: Мне даже стало любопытно, что можно написать про захватыващие группы. Ведь исчерпывающие знания о них описываются двумя предложениями. 1. Захватывающая группа сохраняет результат в отдельную переменную. 2. Если к захватывающей группе применен квантификатор, то будет захвачен первый совпавший кусок текста.